# How set values in pandas dataframe based on NaN values of another column?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, nan

I have dataframe named `df` with original shape `(4361, 15)`. Some of `agefm` column`s values are NaN.  Just look:

```
> df[df.agefm.isnull() == True].agefm.shape
(2282,)
```

Then I create new column and set all its values to 0:

```
df['nevermarr'] = 0
```

So I would like to set `nevermarr` value to 1, then in that row `agefm` is Nan:

```
df[df.agefm.isnull() == True].nevermarr = 1
```

Nothing changed:

```
> df['nevermarr'].sum()
0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you do `df[df.agefm.isnull() == True].nevermarr = 1`, you can drop the `== True` as it already is the output of `isnull`. Then, if it doesn't change I guess it must be because this method creates a copy of your dataframe. Then you modify a temporary dataframe which disappears at the end of the line, not your original dataframe (but I'm not sure). Anyway, Jezrael's answer is good, as always.

Comment: @ysearka That seems to be good explanation))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best is use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['nevermarr'] = np.where(df.agefm.isnull(), 1, 0)
print (df)
   agefm  nevermarr
0    NaN          1
1    5.0          0
2    6.0          0
```

Or use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), `==True` can be omitted:

```
df.loc[df.agefm.isnull(), 'nevermarr'] = 1
```

Or [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['nevermarr'] = df.nevermarr.mask(df.agefm.isnull(), 1)
print (df)
   agefm  nevermarr
0    NaN          1
1    5.0          2
2    6.0          3
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'nevermarr':[7,2,3],
                   'agefm':[np.nan,5,6]})

print (df)
   agefm  nevermarr
0    NaN          7
1    5.0          2
2    6.0          3

df.loc[df.agefm.isnull(), 'nevermarr'] = 1
print (df)
   agefm  nevermarr
0    NaN          1
1    5.0          2
2    6.0          3
```

Comment: Awesome)) But why doesnt the original code work as excepted?

Comment: [ysearka](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37962759/how-set-values-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-nan-values-of-another-column/37962791#comment63372972_37962759) explain it very nice, thanks. And if you need more, check [tomaugspurger blog - part `SettingWithCopy`](http://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-1.html)