# Modifying cell in column B if cell in column A is null

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have null (nan) values in column A and would like to assign 0 to the cells in column B when a cell of the same row in column A is null.

Column B has been created as the following lambda expression :

```
df['col_B'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.col_A in x.col_C, axis=1)
```

I tried to modify it but it doesn't work and from what I read it isn't advised.

So I tried with a classic loop, it shows no error but it doesn't modify the cells in column B :

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['col_A'] is None:
        df.at[index, 'col_B'] = 0
```

My null values appear as "nan" (not "None" or "Nan") so I'm not even sure Python considers them as real null values.

What would you advise ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How set values in pandas dataframe based on NaN values of another column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37962759/how-set-values-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-nan-values-of-another-column)

Answer (score 1):

You should [avoid `pd.Series.apply` wherever possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54432583/9209546). That said, for the conditional assignment there are a few alternatives via Boolean series.

You can use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df['col_A'].isnull(), 'col_B'] = 0
```

Or [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['col_B'] = df['col_B'].mask(df['col_A'].isnull(), 0)
```

Or [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['col_B'] = np.where(df['col_A'].isnull(), 0, df['col_B'])
```

If your nulls are strings, make sure you replace them first; for example:

```
df['col_A'] = df['col_A'].replace('Nan', np.nan)
```